# Is there any module in Azure ML Studio to identify features correlated with a Target Variable and correlated input features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there any module which outputs high/low correlated input features with respect to a given target variable, and which can identify highly correlated input features in a data set in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Such a module would help creating better training data sets and that would allow to create better ML models.

Comment: Azure Machine Learning Studio [comes with modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/feature-selection-modules) that allow to carry out feature selection to mitigate the effects of correlated features, and thus ensure best performance with the given data. They fall in the category of the _feature selection_ functionality of ML Studio.

Comment: Thanks, @DavideFiocco.